# There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code NotFound error in test in web chat

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, botframework, azure-bot-service

I have created a simple empty nodejs chatbot with azure compose. And then created a resource group and published it to azure.
I have followed these 2 links

1. Create a weather chatbot - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/tutorial-create-weather-bot#create-a-new-dialog
2. Deploy the chatbot to azure - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/how-to-publish-bot?tabs=v2x

But I was getting the error HTTP status code NOT Found error.
I tried all the StackOverflow solutions available online none of them worked.

Comment: Can you provide the exact error you are getting?

Comment: Did you attempt to deploy QnA Maker? As the documentation states, that is deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I have deployed a Weather chat-bot to azure using below steps
- I have Created a Weather chat-bot using composer using the Document that you have provide in the above [DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/tutorial-create-weather-bot#create-a-new-dialog).
- It is working in local environment as below

[image: entestrong textr image description here]

- Now you have to deploy to azure portal from the composer for that follow the below steps.
- Click on **Publish** and select **manage profile** as below.

[image]

- Click on **Add new** as below.

[image]

- Goto **Crate new resource** and click on **Next** as below.

[image]

- Fill the all the required details as below and click on **Next**.

[image]

[image]

- After creatin the manage profile and select the profile as below.

[image]

- Click the check box that bot that you want to deploy to azure portal as blow and click on **publish selected bots**.

[image]

- After deploying to azure open resource and click on bot application in azure portal navigate to **test in web chat** and it's working as below.

[image]

- If you deploy it through the Bot composer it will automatically assign the application in sights to your Bot app below is the sample [Add telemetry to your bot - Bot Service | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-telemetry?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp)

[image]

[image]

- For More details refer this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/) follow the step-by-step procedure.